# Transferring Data from .dat file to LinkedList

Tags: c, io, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read data from a dat file ("**boot.dat**") and put it into a LinkedList of Book objects.

At the end of my program the LinkedList data is written to the file.

In this function the file is opened, then an if statement checks to see if the file exists (if it doesn't, it means the program has never been run and then 10 books are inputted by the user)

The else runs the code to transfer the data in from the file to the linkedList. That's my attempt at it. When I run code to display all the books transferred in, it gives me an error of "**Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)"**

Here's the code for the function. Hopefully someone can spot my mistakes.

```
//file data input function
void fileInput()
{
    //open file
    fp = fopen("book.dat", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nCould not open the file book.dat\n");
        printf("\n****************** The database is empty. Books will need to be manually entered ******************\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("\n Book %d of 10:\n");
            printf("----------------\n");
            addBook();
        }
    }else
    {
        //sizing the first book
        firstBook = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        struct node *currentBook = firstBook; //make first record equal current

            struct node *newBook = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


        while(1) //endless while loop. a NULL pointer in final node ends the loop
        {
            fread(currentBook,sizeof(struct bookData),1,fp);
            if(currentBook->next == NULL) //NULL indicates end of list
                break;
            currentBook->next = newBook; //pointer referencing next node
            currentBook = newBook; // make current record new
        }

        printf("\n\nFile data successfully transferred...\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be getting warnings from the compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3386109 I'm using Harvard's CS50's appliance and compiling it in the cmd terminal.

Comment: Hmm, ok, well you need to read the manual and find the command line option that says, "give me every possible warning". (For visual studio, it's `-W4`. For gcc and clang it's `-Wall`.) Using the maximum warning setting, find and fix all of the warnings. If there are some warnings you don't understand, or don't know how to fix, then ask here (with the complete and exact text of the warning). If you compile with maximum warnings and that code doesn't generate any warnings, then you're going to need to get a real compiler.

Comment: What's a `struct node`?  What's a `struct bookData`?  Why aren't they the same data type?  You haven't listed enough code to determine the problem.  Although I will say that you already have one bug which is that you open the file with mode `"r"` but you should should be using mode `"rb"` because you appear to be reading/writing binary data.